# Random No Right-Click Message Not working

Tags: javascript

So we all know that you cannot truly protect your images once you post them, but its a bit of fun to tease the lay person.  I added a script to prevent right-clicking and was trying to randomize funny messages...  its not working.

the script:

```
// BACKGROUND IMAGES
try {
  document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
} catch(err) {}



// no right click
var message=["That doesn't belong to you!  Put the mouse down and no one gets hurt!";
             "Oh, you again.  We of the internet have chosen to defy you!";
         "How would you like it if I walked into your house and tried to help myself to     your furniture?";
         "Hey that tickles!"
         "Thief!  You are being directed to the...  nah just kidding. Enjoy!"]


function clickIE4(){
    if (event.button==2){
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
}

function clickNS4(e){
    if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if (document.layers){
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
    document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

What am I forgetting?  It looks like it should work.  when I remove the [ and ] and reduce it to one message, that message works just fine.  Its when I add additional and attempt to randomize it that the issues occur.

Comment: You are alerting the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are alerting the whole array.
If you want to have random message you could do something like:

```
 var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * message.length);
 alert(message[rn]);
```

This generates a random number out of the number of messages you have in the array.

[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
[Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)